# JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT equivalent in python?

Tags: python, sql, json, pandas

SQL has a very useful function called JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT, which allows to extract data from a json file just by providing the full json path.

What is the easiest way to achieve the same result in python?

I am particularly interested in pandas solutions: *json_normalize* and *read_json* do a good job when the json is not too complex, but they become very difficult to use when the json has multiple nested structures.

Comment: kindly provide an example showing what the sql function does ( specify the version of sql you are referring to) and the difficulty in reproducing the solution in pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with anything that does this out of the box, but it is fairly simple to do. try something like this:

```
from functools import reduce


class JsonPath:
    @classmethod
    def get(cls, data, path):
        return reduce(cls._get_item, path, data)

    @classmethod
    def _get_item(cls, current_data, current_path):
        return current_data.__getitem__(current_path)
```

now lets assume your parsed json (use the `json` built-in) look like this

```
d = {"a": {"b": [1, 2]}}
```

and your datapath is an **iterable** of keys/indices looking like this:

```
data_path = ["a", "b", 1]
```

you can then do:

```
JsonPath.get(d, data_path)
```

and it will return `2`

Comment: This is really neat! I have an issue open for something exactly like this in one of my open source projects, so I think this will really help out. I didn't think of the `functools.reduce` function but that actually simplifies a great deal of the work too! I think that's pretty cool.